# Storing pointer or array of pointers in a dynamic array

Tags: c++

I need to store a dynamic array of elements (std::vector).
Those elements can be a single pointer, or an array of pointers.

I don't want a multidimensional array because it's going to result in a lot of allocations because almost all of the elements are a single pointer.

I want to do this because I want to shuffle the vector or insert elements to it at random positions, but some elements of the vector shouldn't be separated.

What I'm currently thinking is:

```
struct Element
{
    bool isArray;
    union
    {
        void* pointer;
        std::vector<void*> pointers;
    };
};

std::vector<Element> elements;
```

Is there any other good alternative?

Comment: Just wondering, what do you need to do this for?

Comment: To easily randomize the order of chunks of code and data in a linker. Some chunks can't be separated because they must precede or follow another chunk.

Answer (score 0):

If you store vector, each time you add a new pointer to one of the elements you'd be risking heap rearrangement, which could take some time depending on the amount of elements.

I'd recommend you storing vector >, and, in the Element struct, I'd recommend you storing boost::any instead of void*, it tends to be safer, easier to handle and easier to lookup each of the pointers' classes.